# Mencoder doesn't work right in OSX anymore

Tags: subtitles, video-conversion, mencoder

The following works correctly in Linux. However when I try the same thing on the same files in OSX, the subtitles aren't showing.

```
mencoder video.mp4 -vf pp=de,scale=1280:720 \
-oac pcm -o video_subtitled.avi -sub video.srt \
-ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:vbitrate=4317:mbd=2:turbo
```

Mencoder used to work correctly in OSX, but then I made some upgrades. Why aren't the subtitles showing now?